# Why Ansible keeps giving me error "Could not find the requested service httpd: cannot check nor set state"?

Tags: ansible

I am doing a dry run on installing apache web server on a centos 7 box.
This is the webserver.yml file:

```
--- # Outline to Playbook Translation
- hosts: apacheWeb
  user: aleatoire
  sudo: yes
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: date/time stamp for when the playbook starts
    raw: /bin/date > /home/aleatoire/playbook_start.log
  - name: install the apache web server
    yum: pkg=httpd state=latest
  - name: start the web service
    service: name=httpd state=started
  - name: install client software - telnet
    yum: pkg=telnet state=latest
  - name: install client software - lynx
    yum: pkg=lynx state=latest
  - name: log all the packages installed on the system
    raw: yum list installed > /home/aleatoire/installed.log
  - name: date/time stamp for when the playbook ends
    raw: /bin/date > /home/aleatoire/playbook_end.log
```

When I do a dry run with:

```
ansible-playbook webserver.yml --check
```

I keep getting this error:

```
fatal: [<ip_address>]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Could not find the requested service httpd: cannot check nor set state"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/aleatoire/Outline/webserver.retry
```

I tried adding ignore_issues: true and that did not work either.

Comment: `--check` is not going to actually install the httpd package if it's not there yet.  So then the `service:` call will fail if there is no httpd unit file installed yet..

Comment: ahh!..so what's the best way to check for syntax errors after creating yaml files in Ansible?

Comment: With [`--syntax-check`](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Ansible_-_Playbook_Testing.html)

Comment: @GrishaLevit, can you post your response as an answer so I can check it off. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--check` is not going to actually install the httpd package if it's not there yet. So then the `service:` call will fail if there is no httpd unit file installed yet.

You can use [`--syntax-check`](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Ansible_-_Playbook_Testing.html) option instead.